# Calabash-android - how to delay the start of the test scenarios to wait for the app to start?

Tags: android, delay, calabash-android

Once I follow the correct procedure for installing the calabash framework on the App under test, and after writing the test scenarios with the relevant definition step, if I run via console:

```
$ calabash-android console C:\..\app-unaligned.apk
$ start_test_server_in_background
```

The App starts without problems on my device (connected to the pc).

Instead when I run in command prompt:

```
$ calabash-android run C:\..\app-unaligned.apk
```

The App starts after about 40 seconds, which it is obviously too, because in this time range the first two test scenarios have already left, without being able to actually starts in the App. When then the App start (after about 40 seconds) the remaining scenarios (not yet started) are properly executed on App. So the first scenarios fails and the remaining pass.

```
    C:\..\MyApp>calabash-android run C:\..\app-unaligned.apk
    *** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
    Feature: Testing MyApp

    6278 KB/s (585926 bytes in 0.091s)
    6759 KB/s (5721923 bytes in 0.826s)
      Background:                                    # features/my_first.feature:3
      App did not start (RuntimeError)
      ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
        Given I wait                                 # calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/calabash-android/steps/progress_steps.rb:5
        Then I press on the tutorial screen          # features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:3
    .
    .
    Scenario: Test One      # features/my_first.feature:14
    .
    .
    Scenario: Test two    # features/my_first.feature:25
    .
    . 
    Scenario: Test three     # features/my_first.feature:60
    .
    .
    Failing Scenarios:
    cucumber features/my_first.feature:14 # Scenario: Test one
    cucumber features/my_first.feature:25 # Scenario: Test two

    3 scenarios (2 failed, 1 passed)
    56 steps (44 skipped, 12 passed)
    1m12.056s
```

So I wonder if I can delay the start of the test scenarios until real start of the App on mobile, So that all the test scenarios are effectively executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this empty step.

feature:

```
Given App is running
```

step_definition:

```
Given(/^App is running$/) do
end
```

For me this work.

Comment: thanks!! but it does not work for me, the first two scenarios continue to be skipped.

Comment: Maybe try find some element on start page. And add in this step:

wait_for_elements_exist( "* marked:'element'", :timeout => 100)

Comment: In your step_definition I added: "sleep 40"    since the App starts in this range.  I believe that after the Run command, the first scenario is started after a specific time interval, and if in this range the App did not start, the scenario is automatically skipped, without going into individual steps. So it would need a command  to start late the scenarios.

Comment: sleep is fixed. 
wait_for_elements_exist with timeout max 100 sec. But if element exist earlier then 100 sec, system go to next step.

Comment: I tried, but it's the same. i think it would need a command to start late the scenarios, because when the first two scenarious starts i still have:   App did not start (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'